# Can overlap impact the EM algorithm?

Tags: mixed-model, clustering, expectation-maximization, overlapping-data

I am using EM algorithm for clustering. I see that if there is an overlap, the accuracy is reduced. However, it is improvesd if no overlap exists.

My question is, can overlap affect the performance of clustering, in general? Or EM algorithm in specific?

Comment: Overlap affects the clustering performance in general simply because it is harder to distinguish the observations no matter of what algorithm you use. Of course some algorithms are better than the others but all of them struggle more if the clusters are overlapping.

Comment: EM is a numerical algorithm delivering the maximum likelihood estimation. The question should thus focus on the MLE rather than the EM algorithm.